Apache Superset with sqlalchemy-kusto - create dataset - could not load columns
I have installed a new superset (version 4.1.1) with sqlalchemy-kusto==2.0.1. I use kusto sql. I can connect to the Azure Data Explorer. When I want to create a dataset, I got an error:
An Error Occurred Unable to load columns for the selected table. Please select a different table.

I tried this with different tables. Allways the same.
All Databases and all tables of the database were correct listed in the screen. So the connection seems to work.
To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
In settings create a database connection.

Use "kustosql+https://xxx.westeurope.kusto.windows.net/..."
In Datasets create a new Dataset
Select database and table.
An error is displayed: "An Error Occurred Unable to load columns for the selected table. Please select a different table."

Normaly the columns of the table should be displayed.
We made following adaptions to the values.yaml:
bootstrapScript:
...
  pip install psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
  pip install sqlalchemy-kusto==2.0.1

In the logs are 2 error messages:
2024-12-30 10:02:41,496:WARNING:superset.views.error_handling:SupersetErrorException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/superset/sql/parse.py", line 256, in _parse
    return sqlglot.parse(script, dialect=dialect)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/__init__.py", line 102, in parse
    return Dialect.get_or_raise(read or dialect).parse(sql, **opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/dialects/dialect.py", line 919, in parse
    return self.parser(**opts).parse(self.tokenize(sql), sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/parser.py", line 1395, in parse
    return self._parse(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/parser.py", line 1467, in _parse
    self.raise_error("Invalid expression / Unexpected token")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlglot/parser.py", line 1508, in raise_error
    raise error
sqlglot.errors.ParseError: Invalid expression / Unexpected token. Line 1, Col: 14.
  SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM "SmartSignage_Dev"."AssetDimensions"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 95, in wraps
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/superset/views/base_api.py", line 119, in wraps
    duration, response = time_function(f, self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/superset/utils/core.py", line 1364, in time_function
    response = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/superset/utils/log.py", line 303, in wrapper
    value = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/superset/databases/api.py", line 1024, in table_metadata
    payload = database.db_engine_spec.get_table_metadata(database, table)
  File "/app/superset/db_engine_specs/base.py", line 1079, in get_table_metadata
    return get_table_metadata(database, table)
  File "/app/superset/databases/utils.py", line 100, in get_table_metadata
    "selectStar": database.select_star(
  File "/app/superset/models/core.py", line 719, in select_star
    return self.db_engine_spec.select_star(
  File "/app/superset/db_engine_specs/base.py", line 1689, in select_star
    sql = SQLScript(sql, engine=cls.engine).format()
  File "/app/superset/sql/parse.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.statements = statement_class.split_script(script, engine)
  File "/app/superset/sql/parse.py", line 316, in split_script
    ast = cls._parse(remainder, engine)[0]
  File "/app/superset/sql/parse.py", line 259, in _parse
    raise SupersetParseError(
superset.exceptions.SupersetParseError: Error parsing near '100' at line 1:14

Do you have any ideas, how I can solve this problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@MatthiasMor, Can you please edit your question and add the code which is giving the above error? and also what is your expected output?

Double-check the SQL syntax because it indicates the SQL query you're trying to parse using the sqlglot library contains a syntax error.

@Lewis the sql syntax is created from Apache Superset with the sqlalchemy-kusto database driver. So I can´t modify it by hand.

@MatthiasMor I think he problem is with TOP, it's used in SQL Server queries but no in KQL. In KQL do to the same query you have to use take.
